# Ember.js app should redirect to login, when ember-data receive http status 401

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-data

I want my Emberjs application to handle HTTP Status Unauthorized (401).

The application uses ember-data to integrate a JSON API (Rails).

The client layer (Emberjs) should redirect to a Emberjs view/template prompting for login, when receiving  HTTP Status Unauthorized (401).

How can I do this for the entire application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've struggled with the same problem. I've succesfully implemented the following hack.

```
window.App = Em.Application.extend
  ready: ->
    $(document).ajaxError( (event, request, settings) =>
      if request.status == 401 && !["/profile", "/users/sign_in.json"].contains(settings.url)
        controller = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application')
        controller.transitionToRoute('sign_in' )
)
```

The idea is to catch a jQuery ajaxError event. In the event you can check witch the type of error (.e.g. request.status == 401), url that caused the error (e.g. settings.url) and based on that information you can decide what to do.

Hope this helps

Comment: This should be handled by the router now, similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981563/ember-data-handling-401s

Answer (score 8):

I was researching on the same topic and looks like the information here is a little bit outdated. Using Ember 1.7.0, you should handle the error in the route. If you want to apply this to the whole app, you should add it to your `ApplicationRoute` class, like so

```
// app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        error: function (error, transition) {
            // Handle the error here
            if (error && error.status === 401) {
                return this.transitionTo('login');
            }
        }
    }
});

export default ApplicationRoute;
```

This is the same way as the documentation describes it: [read here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-error-code-event)

**Update:** In newer versions of Ember and Ember Data, the error object structure will be a little different. The status will be a string, contained within an error object, within an errors array:

```
actions: {
  error: function(error, transition) {
    if (error.errors[0].status === '401') {
      this.transitionTo('sign-in');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking a better way is to use Ember's **promises**:

```
@store.get("user").then(=>
    # Success stuff here
).fail(=>
    @transitionTo("login") # Do other fancy error stuff here too
)
```

The problem with this is that it would have to be done on all routes individually.  Perhaps you could do something with `beforeTransition` method, checking what the promise returns?  Just food for thought.