# Ember-Data handling 401’s

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Any thoughts on handling 401 errors?

In the application initializer I'm deferring readiness and fetching the current user via ember-data. If I receive a 401 the app dies and becomes unusable. I'd like to handle this error, and then advancereadiness. I cant seem to find a workaround for this. Any info would be appreciated!

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/unknpwn/6126462

I noticed there was a [similar topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349035/emberjs-handle-401-not-authorized), but it seems to be out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.initializer` is not the correct place to put this logic. It is synchronous and it's purpose is to do things like adding custom objects to the IOC container, etc. This code is better suited in the `model` hooks of `ApplicationRoute`.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    return App.User.find({ filter: "authenticated" });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('loggedIn', true);
    controller.set('currentUser', model);// or some property of that model
  },
  events: function() {
    error: function(err) {
      // error handler called in case of an error.
      // show the error message to user here
      // or transition to another route
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know beforeModel existed. I'm still having problems catching the expected 401 error though when I try to get the authenticated user from my API, and subsequently show a login form to the user in place of content. The error function doesn't seem to be hit when the 401 comes back. Any thoughts there?

Comment: There are some bugs where promises swallow some exceptions, this may be one. Try raising an 500 error on the server, see if that triggers the handler.

Comment: As of Ember Data v1.0.0-b3, this works (with the addendum that `events` should be renamed `actions`, as the former has been deprecated.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, `events` or `actions` should be an object, not a function.

Comment: Check out the docs for more info http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-error-code-event

Comment: Note that the action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favour of putting them in an `actions` object .

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is outdated. In current Ember version (1+) `events` are deprecated and you should use `actions` **object** (instead of function).

Ember example:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function(err) {
      // error handler called in case of an error.
      // show the error message to user here
      // or transition to another route
    }
  }
});
```

Ember CLI example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function(err) {
      // error handler called in case of an error.
      // show the error message to user here
      // or transition to another route
    }
  }
});
```

With these action handlers the error will bubble nicely to the main application route if you don't stop it before in your route.