# How can I know the error reason in promise's rejection handler?

Tags: ember.js

I wrote some code using find method like below.
The adapter is RESTAdapter.

```
App.SessionManager = Em.Object.extend({
  userIdChanged: function() {
    App.User.find(this.get('userid')).then(
      function(user) {
        /* process something */
      },
      function(error) {
        /* rejection handler */
        /* I want to know what error returned by the server here.*/
        /* but how? */
      }
    );
  }.observes('userid'),
});
```

If my server returned some error(e.g. 401) the rejection handler called.
But it seems that the argument of handler doesn't have error information.
How can I know the error reason in rejection handler?

Answer (score 2):

Handling of errors returned by the server is not yet fully implemented in ember data.
For reference, as stated in [this blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-data-0-13.html) about ember-data:

> We want to make error handling and dealing with client and server conflicts rock solid. A pull request from Paul Chavard is currently open and looks like a solid starting point for error handling. You should see much more development on this in the near future.

But there are some workaround you can do to get to that information in the meanwhile.

For example:

```
Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  console.log(error.stack);
});
```

Or use a dirty hack to get to that information. Since ember-data uses jQuery under the hood you can subscribe to `ajaxError`:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
  // this will trigger anytime there is an error
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can also override this:

```
becameInvalid: function(record) {
  // you can get errors just by doing record.errors, error keys must match
  // the name of a field that you have defined in your model
}
```

and:

```
becameError: function(record) {
}
```

that's in case something happened in the server that caused an error. I just saw that you want to handle errors on promises, well, that's something different that I haven't dealt with. becameError might be fired.

UPDATE:

I just found something interesting that might help you: [Ember-Data handling 401’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981563/ember-data-handling-401s) thanks to the new router, I haven't had the chance to use all those new features, but they look pretty cool.